# Check When Oracle Database Audit Was Enabled

Tags: sql, oracle

As the title tells, I need to check in which date/time Oracle database audit was enabled and if possible which user did.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find?  Who changed a parameter value?  Or who set up a particular audit rule (i.e. auditing failed logins vs. auditing something else)?  For some time, a basic Oracle install has created a database with auditing enabled and a handful of audit rules configured (i.e. failed logins).

Comment: Yes am looking to check who did and when, as suddenly our DB performance became so high and we found DB audit suddenly ON (while it was OFF) and it is consuming a lot.

Comment: That would normally indicate that someone added an audit rule that was auditing more than they expected it to audit.  Enabling auditing in the database is not something that creates overhead.  And, like I said, unless you explicitly turned it off, auditing is enabled out of the box.  The default set of audit rules is just very lightweight.

Comment: Noted, but doesn't Oracle has any log that says when Audit is enabled or disabled?

Comment: If you are talking about the parameter, no.  Though it seems a bit unlikely that you disabled auditing completely, someone turned on auditing, and that had any impact on the system unless there were a bunch of expensive audit rules defined.  If you are talking about who set up an audit rule, if you've configured auditing to audit changes to audit rules, yes.  But that wouldn't be by default.